# DJango signup list

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

I have this Django model

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import localtime
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.


class Meal(models.Model):
    meal_time = models.DateTimeField("Tid/Dato")
    meal_description = models.CharField(verbose_name="Beskrivelse af måltid", max_length=300)
    meal_deadline = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Tilmeldingsfrist")
    meal_price_pp = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Pris per person", decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    meal_price_tt = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Pris i alt", decimal_places=2, max_digits=5)
    meal_resp = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meal_offer_takeaway = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Tilbyd takeaway", default=False)
    meal_offer_eat_in = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Tilbyd spisning i netværket", default=False)
    # meal_timezone = models.CharField(verbose_name="Tidszone", default='Europe/Copenhagen', max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"{self.meal_description} Dato:"
                f" {localtime(self.meal_time).date().strftime("%d/%m/%Y")} "
                f"{localtime(self.meal_time).strftime("%H:%M")} Pris: {self.meal_price_pp}")

    def weekday(self):
        weekdays = ["Mandag", "Tirsdag", "Onsdag", "Torsdag", "Fredag", "Lørdag", "Søndag"]
        index = self.meal_time.date().weekday()

        return weekdays[index]

    def resp_name(self):
        return self.meal_resp.name


class Participant(models.Model):
    list_user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name="Bruger", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    list_meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, verbose_name="Måltid", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    list_takeaway = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Takeaway", default=False)
    list_eat_in = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Spisning i netværket", default=False)
    list_registration_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date/time registered")
    payment_due = models.DateField(verbose_name="Betales senest")
    payment_status = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Er betalt", default=False)

    def registered_on_time(self):
        meal_record = self.list_meal
        return self.list_registration_time <= meal_record.meal_deadline

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Bruger: {self.list_user}  Dato: {localtime(value=self.list_meal.meal_time).strftime("%x kl. %H:%M")}"
```

And I would like to create a list of Meals where the (authenticated) user can select whether to sign up for a meal (on the Participants list) by selecting (if avalialable) check boxes for eat in, takeaway or both. I have tried using forms but to no avail. I would appreciate if someone could suggest strategies to accomplish this.